# How do I use Universal Membership Provider, EF, and MiniProfiler together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, mvc-mini-profiler

If I use the Universal Membership Provider and a seperate database, Entity Framework and enable Mini Profiler for EF 4.2. I get error `{"There is already an object named 'Applications' in the database."}` when I first hit a line checking user credentials in my home view.

If I turn remove `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();` then I stop getting the error.

Any ideas?

Can I stop profiling the defaultconnection?

Answer (score 1):

I have been banging my head against this issue for awhile now. Did some more digging today and was able to get it working. Here is what I did. In MiniProfiler.cs I defined two methods as follows:

```
public static DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyModelConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    var entityConnStr = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    var realConnection = new SqlConnection(entityConnStr.ProviderConnectionString);
    return realConnection;            
}

public static IMyModelsInterface GetProfiledContext()
{           
     var connection = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection(GetConnection(), MiniProfiler.Current);
     var context = connection.CreateObjectContext<MyModel>();
     return context; 
}
```

**NOTE:** These two methods probably shouldn't be defined in MinProfilerPackage, but this was my first past/hack to get it working.

Then call GetProfiledContext() and use the context returned whenever you want the queries profiled. I injected this profile context into my controller factory using Ninject. My call looks something like this:

```
public NinjectControllerFactory()
{
    ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    AddBindings();
}
private void AddBindings()
{
    var context = MiniProfilerPackage.GetProfiledContext();
    IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(context);
    ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<GenericRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("paramUnitOfWork", uow);  

     // ... rest of the method
 }
```

NinjectControllerFactory is my controller factory that gets set in Application_Start.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     // Add in DI for controller and repo associations
     ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());

     // ... rest of the method
  }
```